# Compiled Uberjar for Groovy Script cannot find class but it is there

Tags: java, groovy, jar, compilation

I want to create an uberjar to let my groovy script run within a cronjob.
When having it compiled with `maven-jar-plugin`, `groovy-eclipse-compiler` and `maven-shade-plugin` all went fine. I did this before with another script and without the following problem.

Now as I compiled the **uberjar** I wanted to run it `java -jar script.jar` I came along this classic message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.myapp.script.ScriptName
```

What I do not understand is that the manifest describes the *Main Class* properly:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: uberjar
Implementation-Version: 7.1.14-12
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Blueprint
X-Compile-Target-JDK: 1.8
Implementation-Build: revision: 20e92d87e6b64a2b70960128798b25d5aca666
 17 - 2018-03-06T09:31:36Z
X-Compile-Source-JDK: 1.8
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Main-Class: com.myapp.script.ScriptName
Implementation-Vendor: Blueprint
```

The `ScriptName.class` file lies within `com/myapp/script/` inside the `.jar` file.

I do not understand what the problem here is and why the MainClass cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was visible within the `com.myapp.script.ScriptName.class` file.
I found out that there was a library missing, this class actually depends on since it **extends** it.

My `maven-shade-plugin` was not configured properly. That's why the library mentioned did not appear in the `.jar`